# Render n screen for shinyglide based on a numericInput

Tags: r, shiny

I try to render a `shinyglide` with a reactive number of screens depending of a numericInput. When the app is initialized it is worked. But, when you modify the numericInput, it is not.
The "next button" is minimized and you can't change screens.

I made a small example to show the problem :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyglide)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "NbScreen",
    label = "Number of screens:",
    value = 3,
    min = 1,
    max = 100
  ),
  uiOutput("glideUI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$glideUI <- renderUI({
    glide(
      lapply(seq_len(input$NbScreen), function(i) {
        screen(p(paste("screen", i)))
      })
    )
  })
  outputOptions(output, "glideUI", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Do you know what I need to do to make this "glide" happen correctly on the reactive side ?

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/juba/shinyglide/issues/42).

Comment: This was fixed in the dev version: `remotes::install_github("juba/shinyglide")`